# Ember i18n dynamic link inside of translation

Tags: ember.js, hyperlink, ember-i18n

I was wondering how I could pass a link into to `{{t}}` helper. I am using v3.0.1 of [Ember i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) at the moment.

Obviously you **cannot** pass a link helper into a t helper (something like

```
{{ t "some-translation-string" link={{#link-to 'page' model}}page{{/link-to}} }}
```

won't work of course).

So I was thinking, maybe I can create a custom prop that returns a whole link. But then again, how do I create that link?. Does anyone know of a method that has the same arguments as the `link-to` helper, but returns just the link (In my case `'page'` and `model`)?

Comment: Why are passing a link into a translation? Do you want a link with a translated name? Or do you want to modify the URL via i18n?

Comment: No it's just a link to another page. Eg: `Go to <a>settings</a> page`. In another language the link can be at a different place in the sentence. So, I want the link within the translation instead in the view.

Comment: For a real solution to this problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265294/link-interpolation-i18n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to achieve that with a basic link, but I doubt that you'll be able to toss a live link-to component inside a translation.

So instead split your translation string into pieces:

```
{{t 'goToSettingPage-before'}}
{{link-to (t 'goToSettingPage-link') 'route.name'}}
{{t 'goToSettingPage-after'}}
```

```
'goToSettingPage-before': 'Go to'
'goToSettingPage-link':   'settings'
'goToSettingPage-after':  'page.'
```

Comment: Yeah I get that. But this is a workaround, not a solution. Still, thanks for pointing me to this direction.

Comment: You basically want the i18n subsystem to work with Handlebars templates rather than text strings.

Comment: Yeah, that would be awesome :P

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper to do exactly what you want using [ember-href-to](https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to).

**Helper:**

```
compute (params) {
  const i18n = this.get('i18n');
  const target = hrefTo(this, params[1]);
  // const targetParam = params[2]; //dynamic segment
  const text = i18n.t(params[0]);

  return Ember.String.htmlSafe('<a href='+ target +'>' + text +'</a>');
}
```

**Template usage:**

```
{{t "linkExample-learnMore" link=(helper-name 'linkExample-here' 'some.route')}}
```

**Translations:**

```
"linkExample-learnMore": "Click {{{link}}} to do something",
"linkExample-here":"here"
```

Comment: Yeah I know now. Back in Februari, I posted as comment to my question: `For a real solution to this problem, see stackoverflow.com/questions/40265294/link-interpolation-i18n‌​.`.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Hopefully this answer will help someone else down the road.